# IE can't use Js class from dynamic loaded script

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, flask

I am trying to dynamicly load a script with jquery and to create an instance of a class from this script.

**My jquery code:**

```
$("#Volumenberechnung").click(function(){
if($(".highlight").length){
    var markierteElemente=$( ".highlight" ).toArray();
    var mask;
    //zuerst das Script der BasisMaske anfragen
    var filename="globalMask.js";
    var dirname="/static/scripts/maskenScripte/"
    var uri="/getScript/"+filename+dirname;
    $.getScript(uri).done(function(script, text){
        mask=new BasicMask(450,700,300,600,xmlKontext);
        mask.setAdditionalMetadata(markierteElemente);
        $.post("/getMask/sendungVolumenberechnung.html").done(function(doc){
                mask.fillWithHTML(doc);
            });
        });
}else{
    alert("Es wurde kein Element ausgewählt!");
}        
});
```

The BasicMaske class is declared in the file I'm loading. When use the IE debugger, i can see that the script is loaded.

For Firefox and Google Chrome this works fine. But the IE is telling me that BasicMask would be an unknown type.

I am testing this with IE 11 and the script is served by the development flask server.

In another script file, I'm also using the jquery $.getScript() method. In this script everything works fine but I'm not instantiating an object or even using the loaded script in the loader script.

Comment: "_BasicMaske class_", do you mean declared with `class` keyword? IE doesn't have support for classes, it is an ES6 feature.

Comment: yes thanks :D i will look for another solution

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
var uri="/getScript/"+filename+dirname
```

try

```
var uri="/getScript" + dirname + filename
```

Comment: No the path was rigth. The problem was the class keyword.